# Can't write JSON to file located inside Eclipse J2EE Project

Tags: java, json, eclipse, servlets, outputstream

Got a problem, and i just can't figure it out, even with many researches. Novice kind of trouble i guess...
I've got a Java Servlet in J2EE app , that get data, treat it, and write a JSON file with it (with GSON).
The aim is to allow javascript to get that json file from the web app.

If the json file is located somewhere on the computer (desktop for example), java servlet will find it and writte it well.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\AM337866\\Desktop\\data.json",false);
writeJsonStream(out, data);
```

But as this is a web-app, i don't want that file to be stored on the computer, plus, javascript won't be able to get it.

So i thought about locating it at the root of the web-app project, so that JS could get the data. But then the servlet can't find the file anymore, and so write does not occur.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./data.json",false);
```

I'm doing something wrong here, maybe i'm not using the good method to write on a file inside the web-app project. Not even sure this is the right way to store json in J2EE app.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Files inside the web application archive (or WAR) cannot be located by their disk paths for two reasons: the first is that they are zipped and therefore a normal path cannot point to them, and the second is that the actual location of the zip file could vary from one installation to another and therefore a fixed path is not good because it would change very often.

Files inside JARs and WARs are located as *Java Resources*, which can be handled by the Java class loader using the [getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)%20getResourceAsStream()) method, which returns an `InputStream` to the resource. Note that the path you pass to this method depends on the location of the class from which the method is called if you do not provide an absolute path, for example if you have a class `Test.java` and `test.json` file located in the same folder as the class, you can open an `InputStream` for the resource like this:

```
InputStream input = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('test.json');
```

This looks for the resource using the same class loader that loaded the `Test` class. Note that here we refer to the *compiled* class, not the source code (so the `test.json` file has to be inside the JAR file where `Test.class` is, usually however when the project is compiled all files that are not Java classes are copied to the classpath without modification.

Note that Java class loaders are a complex subject as an application can have several class loaders. Multi-threading complicates things further.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured how to make the servlet find the json file and write it.

```
 String path = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path+"\\data.json",false);
```

It works fine, but once the application will be deployed, i don't think that will work anymore. So that makes me think, is it the right way to store Json file, at the root of the WebContent?

Comment: This works only if the file you're searching is not inside a JAR that is inside the WAR file

Comment: The usual way to access this kind of resources is to define a configurable location (a folder) to store and retrieve it. You can see this as a staging area, or a temp folder, depending on how long the data should stay there.

Comment: EmirCalabuch so you mean if i generate a WAR file to deploy the app, this won't work? So the data.json should be located in Java Resources? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to access this kind of resources is to define a configurable location (a folder) to store and retrieve it. You can think of it this as a staging area, or a temp folder, depending on how long the data should stay there.

There are many ways to define it. For instance, I usually use spring to inject the configurable location.

As it is configurable per environment (DEV, TEST, PROD etc ...), I recommend to use an absolute path, like you did in your code sample. Relative path (i.e relative to your installation) can only increase confusion and reduce portability of your code (unit test, webapp, runnable jar etc....)

Classpath resources can be useful too, but I don't think this fits your needs in this specific case.